# Access build events without using DTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix

When capturing build events you can simply listen to the `DTE2.Events.BuildEvents` event. However is it possible to listen to these events without the use of `DTE`. I have read and heard from several people and sources that you should generally avoid using `DTE`, if somehow possible, due to its bad implementation or whatever.

Comment: `DTE` is the main application object for Visual Studio. I haven't seen/heard any of those claims about so-called "bad implementation" but I suspect it comes from an outsider's view of Visual Studio's COM origins and underpinnings. The surface area is necessitated by the `IDispatch` nature of those event interfaces. It's not pretty, I'll admit. But I don't think it's as bad as they've made it out to be.

Comment: And for the punchline, `DTE` is what publishes those events so no, there is no other way to listen to them.

Comment: @madreflection Well then, I guess that answers my question. I thought you could get around using `DTE` since you can get the `IVsSolutionEvents` without directly using the `DTE2.Events` object.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "native" interfaces. Microsoft is a master of abstraction and indirection. It's entirely possible that they're just abstractions over the old ones. Take `IVsSolution.GetGuidOfProject`, for example. It still returns an HRESULT and uses an output parameter for the `Guid` result. If they were true .NET interfaces, I doubt they would continue to use COM paradigms. If the native interfaces are better, it's just because they provide a better surface area, not better functionality.

Comment: Yea, I just noticed them as well. For now I need to figure out how I will get to the [IVsBuildableProjectCfg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildableprojectcfg?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you're trying to automate Visual Studio you can either use DTE, which is the standard automation approach, or use native interfaces. The native interfaces start 'IVs...', e.g. IVsSolution.  In both cases the technology is ancient and poorly-documented.  As you suggest, a native solution does tend to be better.

Having said that, for the tasks running on a build that I've needed I ended up using DTE, which can be easier to program and made to work reliably.

I've found the equally-ancient articles (not the tools!) on the mztools.com website to be quite useful on this stuff, as well as the MSDN docs of course.  Add 'mztools' to your Google search.  For example, what [mztools says on build events](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007029.aspx) (Google 'mztools build events') is useful even though it dates from 2013.

Comment: Thanks a lot though! The link you pointed to turned out to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share the code which actually works and achieves exactly what I needed. This was possible through the help of @Rich N, thanks for that one. It is actually easier than I thought, it is always the same procedure

1. Get the `Svs...` class from the `GetService` method and cast it to the corresponding interface.
2. Than append the Event Handler Class with the `Advise...` method.

```cs
// First of get the IVsSolutionBuildManager via the SVsSolutionBuildManager with the GetService method
var service = GetService(typeof(SVsSolutionBuildManager)) as IVsSolutionBuildManager;

// Appending the Events
service.AdviseUpdateSolutionEvents(new Events(), out var cookie)

// The class which handles the Event callbacks
public class Events : IVsUpdateSolutionEvents
{
   // The implemented methods from the interface
}
```